# How can you get the modification time of a file in a cross platform manner?

Tags: rust

The stable `MetadataExt` trait offers some basic functionality for this purpose, but it doesn't work on Windows.

I also see [this RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/939) on the topic of I/O reform  but now I'm totally confused. Wasn't the reason we took so long to get a 1.0 stable because of the absolutely epic feedback on the I/O story for Rust?

Why are the [*experimental*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/) `std::os::unix::fs::MetadataExt` traits in stable, when there is no cross platform story for the same functionality?

Is there some standard crate that I haven't found for this purpose? This question refers to Rust 1.3.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, there is a crate for this: [`filetime`](https://crates.io/crates/filetime) (pointed out by Vladimir Matveev).  Just be aware that the `FileTime::seconds` method in that crate is *platform specific*.

Secondly, 1.0 was about building the *foundation* for the language, not the complete standard library.  It shipped with a *lot* of things that you might normally expect missing.  Quite a few are *still* missing (as of 1.3).  Part of this is is that the core team are *very* conservative about what they'll promise to support, given how seriously they're taking backward compatibility.

Third, `MetadataExt` isn't experimental.  It's stable.  It just happens to be platform-specific.

Fourth, `MetadataExt` is actually a bit of a red herring.  The *actual* problem here is that `rustdoc` is built as a kind of post-process of the compiler, inserted after type checking is done.  This puts it *after* macro expansion.  This is relevant because it's during macro expansion that platform-specific `#[cfg(...)]` attributes are resolved.  *This* is important because this is how the language does platform-specific code.

As a result, docs are only built for the platform you're specifically targeting.  The docs on the official website *all* target Linux.  As a result, *nothing* Windows-specific shows up.  Now, if you download the Windows compiler, it comes with a set of docs, and *those* docs target Windows.  If you open those up and search, you'll find `std::os::windows::fs::MetadataExt`, which looks like this:

```rust
pub trait MetadataExt {
    fn file_attributes(&self) -> u32;
    fn creation_time(&self) -> u64;
    fn last_access_time(&self) -> u64;
    fn last_write_time(&self) -> u64;
    fn file_size(&self) -> u64;
}
```

(I can't just link to this for hopefully obvious reasons.)

As an aside, what you linked to isn't an RFC; it's an issue on the RFC repository.  It's for tracking things that RFCs should be written about.

So, to wrap this all up: you can use the aforementioned crate *or* you can write platform-specific code, which will likely boil down to one path for Windows, and one path for everything else, using the two different `MetadataExt` traits.  One thing to be careful of is that the two systems use different epochs, meaning the times aren't directly comparable.  UNIX uses an epoch of Jan 1 1970, Windows uses Jan 1 1601.

The simplest thing is probably to just use the crate mentioned above.

Comment: There is a library for this, called [filetime](https://github.com/alexcrichton/filetime). It provides cross-platform access to various file timestamps.

Comment: no thanks, no need for more dependencies to do something so simple

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Rust 1.10, there is a [`Metadata::modified` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/struct.Metadata.html#method.modified) to get the modification time.

Comment: `Metadata::modified` returns a [`SystemTime`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html), which requires the use of [`UNIX_EPOCH`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/time/constant.UNIX_EPOCH.html) _"...as an anchor in time to learn information about a `SystemTime`."_, since _"a `SystemTime` cannot be directly inspected."_ Thus, `Metadata::modified` is not cross-platform.

Comment: Is it not cross platform? UNIX_EPOCH is "defined to be “1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC” on all systems "

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I have in my util's module. Pass the path and get the modified unix timestamp in seconds.

```
use std::fs;
use std::time::UNIX_EPOCH;

pub fn file_modified_time_in_seconds(path: &str) -> u64 {
    fs::metadata(path)
    .unwrap()
    .modified()
    .unwrap()
    .duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH)
    .unwrap()
    .as_secs()
}
```